# How to do remote staging in liferay 6.1.1 GA2?

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

I have a site when I tried to apply local staging it's worked fine,but we I tried to connect it through remote server it's not working giving error connection can't be established.Does any one tried it?

This is the configuration with the error message:

[image: Configuration with error message]

Answer (score 0):

[This blog post](https://www.liferay.com/web/olaf.kock/blog/-/blogs/setting-up-remote-staging-through-https) (disclaimer: my own) explains how to do it with https - you can omit long parts of it if you don't want encryption. It also covers 6.0, but the general principle is still the same.

You want to pay special attention to the paragraph *Allow access to webservices* in that article and check if your publishing server (the "stage") has access to the live server. In general, if this is not on localhost, it requires configuration as mentioned in that article.

As you indicate that you can't connect to your production server from your staging server, please check by opening a browser, running on the staging server and connect it to the production server - go to `http://production-server-name:8080/api/axis` and validate that you can connect (note: You get the authoritative result for this test only when not accessing localhost as the production system: Do run the browser on the staging system!) - with this test you can eliminate the first chance of your remote system being disallowed. Once this succeeds, you'll need credentials for the production server to be entered on the staging server - the account that you use needs to have permissions to change all the data it needs to change when publishing content (and pages etc.)

The error message you give in the added screenshot can appear when the current user on staging does not have access to the production system (with the credentials used) - verify that you have the same user account that you are using on your staging system (the one that gets the error message from the screenshot) in your production system. Synchronize the passwords of the two.

I your comment you give the information that you're using different version for the staging and the production environment - I don't expect that to work, so this might be the root cause. Test with both systems at the same version.

Comment: Olaf,Thanks for the blog link,I have followed the points you have mentioned,but still it didn't worked as i am getting error you don't have permission. I have mentioned the Id of the default group as the remoteId, do I have missed any thing? also does different version of liferay may cause any problem like remote is on liferay6.1.0 EE GA1 and local is on liferay6.1.1 CE GA2?

Comment: Also FYI I am not using any secure protocol.

Comment: edited the answer - I don't expect it to work with different versions

Comment: Olaf,i tried it over same version of liferay ,still it's giving the error message that you don't have permission to edit group(i.e. Remote Site ID),do I have missed any thing?how to manage the permission for remote group?

Comment: Try with the added test - and please give more steps and precise error messages (and where you get them) - you might add them to your question, so that it contains more helpful information and others don't need to search for it in comments. Also - note that you find the siteID to use in the production system's "Site Settings" in Control Panel. It's numeric

Comment: Olaf,please check the images i have uploaded

Comment: "verify that you have the same user account that you are using on your staging system" ..Yes using the same user.

Also using the same LR version.

Answer (score 0):

A couple important points to keep in mind with remote publishing:

1. If you're not on LDAP (or you have different LDAPs for different environments), you should validate that your user account is exactly the same in both source and target environments.  So, if you're on the QA site and you want to remote publish to production, your screen name, email address, and password should all be the same.
2. Email address is uber important.  Depending on which distribution (version) of Liferay you are on, the remote publish code uses your email address to irrespective of whether or not you have portal-ext.properties configured to use screenname.
3. You should have the Administrator role in on both sides.  It may not be required in every scenario, but giving that role out to users that do remote publishing has saved me time and effort debugging why someone's remote publish didn't work.  Debugging this process takes a very long time.
4. If remote publishing is causing you problems (and it probably is or you wouldn't be here), try doing lar file exports / imports.  This is important since remote publish failures are not exactly helpful in telling you what failed, they just tell you then failed.  Surprisingly, there are often problems in the export process and you can sometimes pinpoint some bad documents or a funky development thing you did using Global scope and portlet preferences that caused your RP to fail.  I generally use this order in this situation a) documents and media [exclude thumbnails or your lar file will likely double in size, also exclude ranks if you're not using them] from the wrench icon in the control panel b) web content from the wrench icon in the control panel c) public pages [include data > web content display, but remove all the other data check boxes], include permissions, include categories d) private pages [same options as public pages].
5. If you already have Administrator role and it's saying you don't have permissions to RP to the remote site, setup your user on the target environment with the "Site Administrator" or "Site Owner" role.
6. A little late for first and foremost, but anytime you have something that's not working (remote publishing or otherwise), check the logs before you do anything else.  The Liferay code base doesn't include a lot of helpful logging, but you do occasionally get a nugget of information that helps you piece together enough to do root cause analysis.

Cheers!  HTH